# Dynamic cross-domain-content in firefox addon

Tags: ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a Firefox add-on and i need to allow dynamically new domain in "cross-domain-content" because my users can specify the API url where my add-on is connected.

Script : user specify api url -> allow this url for ajax in "contentScript" -> ajax call

Thanks

Comment: which API are you using that needs cross domain permissions?

Comment: yes, please provide more info

Comment: no, which firefox APIs are you using that you need to behave differently